# Handling multiple inheritance w/ different call signs

Tags: python, design-patterns

So this is kind of a python design question + multiple heritance. I'm working on a program of mine and I've ran into an issue I can't figure out a decent way of solving.

To keep it simple. The software scans a log event file generated from another program. Initially it creates and stores each event in a representative event object. But I want to access them quickly and with a more robust language so I'm loading them into a SQL DB after doing a little processing on each event, so theres more data than previous. When I query the DB I'm wanting to recreate an object for each entry representative of the event so its easier to work with.

The problem I'm running into is that I want to avoid a lot of duplicate code and technically I should be able to just reuse some of the code in the original classes for each event. Example:

```
 class AbstractEvent:
    __init__(user, time)
    getTime()
    getUser()
 class MessageEvent(AbstractEvent):
    __init__(user,time,msg)
    getMessage()
 class VideoEvent(AbstractEvent):
    pass
```

But, there is extra data after its gone into the DB so there needs to be new subclasses:

```
 class AbstractEventDB(AbstractEvent):
    __init__(user, time, time_epoch)
    getTimeEpoch()
    (static/classmethod) fromRowResult(row)
 class MessageEventDB(AbstractEventDB, MessageEvent):
    __init__(user, time, msg, time_epoch, tags)
    getTags()
    (static/classmethod) fromRowResult(row)
 class VideoEventDB(AbstractEventDB, VideoEvent):
    pass
```

This is a simpler version than whats happening, but it shows some of what does happen. I change long form time stamps from the log file into epoch timestamps when they go into the DB and various tags are added on message events but other events have nothing extra really beyond the timestamp change.

The above is ideally how I would like to format it, but the problem I've ran into is that the call signatures are completely different on the DB object side compared to the Simple Event side; so when I try to call super() I get an error about expected arguements missing.

I was hoping someone might be able to offer some advice on how to structure it and avoid duplicating code 10-20 times over, particularly in the fromRowResult (a factory method). Help much appreciated.

Comment: Simplify your design somehow - e.g. do it only in Python, or create the initial version of the object with already expected members, or skip your wish to use inheritance. Be pragmatic, do not overoptimize.

Answer (score 0):

I thin what you are looking for is a Python implementation for the decorator design pattern.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

The main idea is to replace multiple inheritance with inheritance + composition:

```
class  AbstractEvent(object):
    def __init__(self, user, time):
        self.user = user
        self.time = time


class MessageEvent(AbstractEvent):
    def __init__(self, user, time, msg):
        super(MessageEvent, self).__init__(user, time)
        self.msg = msg


class AbstractEventDBDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, event, time_epoch):
        # event is a member of the class. Using dynamic typing, the event member will
        # be a AbstractEvent or a MessageEvent at runtime. 
        self.event = event
        self.time_epoch = time_epoch

    @classmethod
    def fromRowResult(cls, row):
        abstract_event = AbstractEvent(row.user, row.time)
        abstract_event_db = AbstractEventDBDecorator(abstract_event, row.time_epoch)
        return abstract_event_db


class MessageEventDB(AbstractEventDBDecorator):

    def __init__(self, message_event, time_epoch, tags):
        super(MessageEventDB, self).__init__(message_event, time_epoch)
        self.tags = tags

    @classmethod
    def fromRowResult(cls, row):
        message_event = MessageEvent(row.user, row.time, row.msg)
        message_event_db = MessageEventDB(message_event, row.time_epoch, row.tags)
        return message_event_db


class Row:
    def __init__(self, user, time, msg, time_epoch, tags):
        self.user = user
        self.time = time
        self.msg = msg
        self.time_epoch = time_epoch
        self.tags = tags


if __name__ == "__main__":
    me = MessageEvent("user", "time", "msg")
    r = Row("user", "time", "Message", "time_epoch", "tags")
    med = MessageEventDB.fromRowResult(r)
    print med.event.msg
```